# How to get the next Monday using PHP strtotime?

Tags: php, variables, strftime

I am using this to variable to get the current month:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, array('ro.utf-8', 'ro_RO.UTF-8', 'ro_RO.utf-8', 'ro', 'ro_RO', 'ro_RO.ISO8859-2')); 

$month = " " . strftime('%B',time()) . " ";

echo date("d", strtotime("next monday")); echo $luna;  echo date("Y", strtotime("next monday"));
```

Currently it's working good, but when the month it's almost end and the next Monday it's next month, it will show the wrong month because my variable is getting the current month.

I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: Are you using `$month` and `$luna` as the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error here `strftime('%B',time())`, actualy it should be `strftime('%B',strtotime("next monday"))`.

```
<?php

$next_monday_timestamp = strtotime("next monday");
echo "Next monday will be on " . strftime("%B", $next_monday_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `strftime` to get the month name in Romanian, but then adding the day and year numeric values with `date` and `strtotime`. You don't need to do that. `strftime` can do the whole thing.

```
echo strftime("%d %B %Y", strtotime("next monday"));
```

This is much more straightforward. There only needs to be one call to `strtotime` to get the timestamp for next monday, and then you use `strftime` to format that timestamp according to your locale.